# when to use this.getInitialView = this.getInitialView.bind(this);

Tags: javascript, react-native

*I am following [Getting started with React Native and Firebase](https://medium.com/@jamesmarino/getting-started-with-react-native-and-firebase-ab1f396db549#.j8rwk2d8z) tutorial on medium.
I came across below code.*

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Firebase.initialise();
    this.getInitialView();
    this.state = {
      userLoaded: false,
      initialView: null
    };
    //What this code does?
    this.getInitialView = this.getInitialView.bind(this);
  }

  getInitialView() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      let initialView = user ? "Home" : "Login";
      this.setState({
        userLoaded: true,
        initialView: initialView
      })
    });
  }
```

*can some body explain below statement? when and why should i use it? and what are all the advantages?*

`this.getInitialView = this.getInitialView.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically anytime you want to use `this`, you want it to be referring to the component. ES6 Classes don't autobind, so there are multiple ways to handle this issue:

1. You can bind in the constructor like in your example.
2. You can use an arrow function wherever you call your method: `( ) => this.getInitialView( )`.
3. You can bring in a library to autobind the methods for you.
4. **I do it this way:** When defining the methods, do it like this, since arrow functions do not define a scope of their own:

   `getInitialView = () => {
     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       let initialView = user ? "Home" : "Login";
       this.setState({
         userLoaded: true,
         initialView: initialView
       })
     });
   }`

Answer (score 1):

It bind the `this`  keyword to the react component. Otherwise you couldn't use `this` inside the method.

The difference is without the line you question `this` would refer to something else and not have setState as a function which is important to react components.

<del>It does appear though, given the context, that it's not used because the only usage of `this` is in another function it should change the context. I'd think you'd need to do to achieve the desired results. (code snippet removed)</del>

Comment: hey thanks for your quick reply. i am new to react-native can you provide some example and explanation

Comment: I expanded my example with what i would expect should be correct. Take a look. Without the line you question `this` would refer to something else and not have `setState` as a function.

Comment: Since he's using an arrow function, I don't think he needs to do the `that = this`